# Building sqlite for windows in a proper way

Tags: sql, sqlite, gcc, compiler-optimization

My problem is no matter how I build sqlite - my binary is much slower than
the precompiled one on sqlite download page (about 3 - 6 times depending on
the query).

I am using sqlite3.h and sqlite3.c from the amalgamation source:

http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3070602.zip

I have added the following flags when compiling sqlite:

```
gcc
-s -O4 -I. -fomit-frame-pointer
-DNDEBUG
-DSQLITE_OS_WIN=1
-DSQLITE_HAVE_READLINE=0
-DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1
-DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3
-DSQLITE_OMIT_COMPILEOPTION_DIAGS
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA
-DNO_TCL
```

I built it both with MINGW and with MSVS 2010.

Does anyone one know how to build sqlite to get the same binary as on
download page ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But why would you want to?  Just download it.

Comment: @MAW74656: You may well want to embed it so the compiler can optimise the entire codebase, optimise memory use, or just so you don't have to load a DLL and deal with all the ramifications of that. Embedding it inside an app is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the guide on [SQLite wiki : How to compile](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=HowToCompile) and check what are the arguments `Make` passes to the compiler. My first suspect would be `-O4`, as the highest level GCC understands is `-O3`, and even this usually turns out worse than `-O2` or `-Os` (because small size == no CPU cache misses, and `-O3` bloats the binary really badly).

Although I can see the approach differs: [Build On Windows Without Tcl](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=BuildOnWindowsWithoutTcl) uses `-O2`, but ticket [#931](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/tktview?tn=931) uses the damned `-O4` "Gentoo Ricer Mode". Either way, those optimization switches aren't worth much without specifying target architecture: try `-march=core2` or `-march=native` for auto-detection, but remember that such code won't work on earlier CPUs. `-march=nocona` will work on anything newer than Pentium 4 and still gives the compiler a lot of room for useful optimizations.

Comment: Any idea what options were used to build the downloadable binaries for Windows?

Comment: Same here, makefile doesn't work. I'm pretty sure there is a list of keys for dll compilation somewhere, but how one can aquire them?